# How to limit a string option parameter length in python click

Tags: python, python-click

I am implementing a python CLI with [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/). I wait to add an optional string parameter `--name` but I want to its length. Is there a native way to do that with click? e.g. some option to pass to `@option`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the validation yourself by checking the length and raising a length error for the end user to know, but otherwise, there is no built-in way for click to enforce that